# Ruby / Rails rake task doesn't end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rake-task, whenever

Till today everything works ok, task was executed, for some time it uses almost 100% of CPU end were removed. But now, tasks doesn't ends and overload server.

I use whenever gem and schedule.rb like:

```
every 5.minutes do
  rake "my_app:mailing:send"
end
```

Does anyone had that kind of problem ? I use VPS 6 Core and 16GB of RAM. I do not change anything on server in last days.

Comment: I had similar issue. Problem was related to convert graphics from email from pop server. I used htop to  find process and then kill it. Do you put some attahments to email?

Comment: Yes, emails always had graphics. But this rake task is only one of many that from today are executed very long time ... strange, I do not make any changes in app or server.

Comment: In my case app work propertly about few years and I meet this problem 3 week ago. I suppose that there were specific file with error that cause problem.

Comment: I just get answer from server provider - they change disc and everything back to normal!  :) So in my case it was hardware problem. Thanks for try to help.